# Bash script prompt to run dynamic set of commands

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a script that will contain multiple commands which the user will be prompted to run up front, and run a dynamic set of those commands based on user input

So, lets say for example I setup functions for the commands that I need to run

```
    command1 () { some_command; }
    command2 () { some_command; }
    command3 () { some_command; }
    command4 () { some_command; }
```

Followed by a series of prompts

```
Do you want to run command1?
Do you want to run command2?
Do you want to run command3?
Do you want to run command4?
```

For this example, assume Y, N, Y, Y so I need to run command1, command3, command4
I hope that gets the point across.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The read command is just what you need http://www.vias.org/linux-knowhow/bbg_sect_08_02_01.html

short example

Applying user input to the variable 'foo'

```
# Just showing a nice message along with it.
echo -n "Would you like to run command1? (Y/N) "
read foo
```

Then you could just test the value of the foo variable

```
if [ "$foo" == "Y" ]; then
  command1
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

```
read -p "Do you want to run command1? " c1  
read -p "Do you want to run command2? " c2  
read -p "Do you want to run command3? " c3  
read -p "Do you want to run command4? " c4

if [ "$c1" = "Y" ]; then  
    command1  
fi  

if [ "$c2" = "Y" ]; then  
    command2  
fi

if [ "$c3" = "Y" ]; then  
    command3  
fi

if [ "$c4" = "Y" ]; then  
    command4  
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You might (or might not) want to consider the `select` built-in:

> `select`
>
> The select construct allows the easy generation of menus. It has almost the
>   same syntax as the for command:
>
> ```
> select name [in words ...]; do commands; done
> ```
>
> The list of words following in is expanded, generating a list of items. The set of
>   expanded words is printed on the standard error output stream, each preceded
>   by a number. If the ‘in words’ is omitted, the positional parameters are printed,
>   as if ‘in "$@"’ had been specified. The PS3 prompt is then displayed and a line
>   is read from the standard input. If the line consists of a number corresponding
>   to one of the displayed words, then the value of name is set to that word. If
>   the line is empty, the words and prompt are displayed again. If EOF is read,
>   the select command completes. Any other value read causes name to be set
>   to null. The line read is saved in the variable REPLY.
>
> The commands are executed after each selection until a break command is
>   executed, at which point the select command completes.

Answer (score 0):

If you took user input into a series of variables (using the read command as detailed in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12151570/920798)), one for each command (call them, for example, C1, C2, C3) then after you've taken user input you can write a series of if statements that looks at the value of those variables

```
if [ $C1 == "Y" ]; then
    command1
fi

if [ $C2 == "Y" ]; then
    command2
fi

if [ $Cn == "Y" ]; then
    commandN
fi
```

Does that help at all?